# Como acessar um objeto por uma variável?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Tenho dois `select`s que envia pro evento `change` o valor de `data-id` e atribuo à variável `tipo`.

Tenho dois objetos cada qual com valores nas chaves `1:` e `2:`.

Usando `tipoUm[1]` me retorna o valor `1.10` normal. Mas se eu usar a variável `tipo` para acessar o objeto, desta forma `tipo[1]`, eu não consigo acessar o objeto, e sim me é retornado a segunda string da variável `tipo`, ou seja, o `i` (de `tipoUm` ou `tipoDois`).

Como eu consigo pegar o valor da chave `1:`, por exemplo, dos objetos de acordo com o valor da variável `tipo` no evento?

```js
var tipoUm = {
   1: 1.10,
   2: 2.50,
};

var tipoDois = {
   1: 2.20,
   2: 4.70,
};

$(".tipo").on('change', function(){

   var tipo = $(this).data("id");
   console.log(tipo);
   
   // a variável "tipo" pode ser: tipoUm ou tipoDois
   // pegar o valor da chave "1" do objeto de acordo com a
   // variável "tipo"

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="tipo" data-id="tipoUm">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
</select>

<select class="tipo" data-id="tipoDois">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar `window[variavel]`. Ficaria assim

```js
var tipoUm = {
   1: 1.10,
   2: 2.50,
};

var tipoDois = {
   1: 2.20,
   2: 4.70,
};

$(".tipo").on('change', function(){

   var tipo = $(this).data("id");
   console.log(window[tipo][1]);
   
   // Acessa a propriedade "tipo" do objeto window. pode ser: tipoUm ou tipoDois
   // pegar o valor da chave "1" do objeto de acordo com a
   // variável "tipo"

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="tipo" data-id="tipoUm">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
</select>

<select class="tipo" data-id="tipoDois">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
</select>
```

Vale lembrar que isso só funciona para variáveis globais, como no caso do exemplo que você colocou. Creio que outra solução seria usar `eval`

Comment: Realmente. Na verdade o escopo dos objetos era local mesmo, mas resolveu tranquilo.

Comment: Com `eval` ou com `window`? Fico feliz que resolveu o problema ;)

Comment: usei window mesmo :D

Answer (score 3):

Pessoalmente sugiro outra abordagem ao problema. Se é você que controla os objetos então pode codifica-los de forma diferente a fim de dar mais jeito no código, assim:

```
var opcoes = {
  tipoUm : {
     1: 1.10,
     2: 2.50,
  },
  tipoDois : {
     1: 2.20,
     2: 4.70,
  }
}
```

Assim combina todas as opções num só objeto, e pode agora usar o tipo como chave deste objeto, ficando bem simples de utilizar:

```
opcoes[tipo][1]
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var opcoes = {
  tipoUm : {
     1: 1.10,
     2: 2.50,
  },
  tipoDois : {
     1: 2.20,
     2: 4.70,
  }
}
$(".tipo").on('change', function(){

   var tipo = $(this).data("id");
   console.log(opcoes[tipo][1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="tipo" data-id="tipoUm">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
</select>

<select class="tipo" data-id="tipoDois">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Realmente, bem melhor mesmo, assim evita o escopo global.

Comment: @dvd Que é sempre problemático xD

Comment: Melhor opção, sem dúvida.